# AngleSharp error while making the async calls

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, anglesharp

I am trying to load many pages using the [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp). The idea is that it loads a page, and if this page has a link to the next, loads the next page and so forth, the methods are described like bellow. But I am getting the inner exception:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index"
```

I believe is something related with `Thread` and syncrhronization.

```
    public static bool ContainsNextPage(IDocument document)
    {
        String href = document.QuerySelectorAll(".prevnext a")[0].GetAttribute("href");
        if (href == String.Empty)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static string GetNextPageUrl(IDocument document)
    {
        return document.QuerySelectorAll(".prevnext a")[0].GetAttribute("href");

    }

    public static async Task<IDocument> ParseUrlSynch(string Url)
    {
            var config = new Configuration().WithDefaultLoader();
            IDocument document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(Url);

            return document;
    }

    public static async Task<ConcurrentBag<IDocument>> GetAllPagesDOMs(IDocument initialDocument)
    {

        ConcurrentBag< IDocument> AllPagesDOM = new ConcurrentBag< IDocument>();
        IDocument nextPageDOM;
        IDocument currentDocument = initialDocument;

        if (initialDocument != null)
        {
            AllPagesDOM.Add(initialDocument);
        }

        while (ContainsNextPage(currentDocument))
        {
            String nextPageUrl = GetNextPageUrl(currentDocument);

            nextPageDOM = ParseUrlSynch(nextPageUrl).Result;
            if (nextPageDOM != null)
                AllPagesDOM.Add(nextPageDOM);

            currentDocument = nextPageDOM;
        }

        return AllPagesDOM;
    }

      static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        List<IDocument> allPageDOMs = new List<IDocument>();
        IDocument initialDocument = ParseUrlSynch(InitialUrl).Result;
        List<String> urls = new List<string>();
        List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>();
        IHtmlCollection<IElement> subjectAnchors = initialDocument.QuerySelectorAll(".course_title a");

        String[] TitleAndCode;
        String Title;
        String Code;
        String Description;
        IDocument currentDocument = initialDocument;


        ConcurrentBag<IDocument> documents =          

        GetAllPagesDOMs(initialDocument).Result; //Exception in here
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message is caused by this code:

```
document.QuerySelectorAll(".prevnext a")[0]
```

One of your documents doesn't have any anchors inside `prevnext`. Maybe it's first page, maybe the last, either way you need to check the array for it's length.

Also blocking call on async method is a bad practice and should be avoided. You'll get the deadlock in any UI app. The only reason you don't get it now is that you're in console app.

Answer (score 0):

Your instincts are correct, if you are using this from an application with a non-default `SynchronizationContext` such as WPF, Win Forms, or ASP.NET then you will have a deadlock because you are synchronously blocking on an `async` `Task` returning function (this is bad and should be avoided). When the first `await` is reaching inside of the blocking call, it will try to post the continuation to the current `SyncronizationContext`, which will be already locked by the blocking call (if you use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` you avoid this, but that is a hack in this case).

A quick fix would be to use async all the way through by changing:

```
nextPageDOM = ParseUrlSynch(nextPageUrl).Result;
```

with:

```
nextPageDOM = await ParseUrlSynch(nextPageUrl);
```

After you get stung by this a few times, you'll learn to have alarm bells go off in your head every time you block an asynchronous method.